# how to open windows form control in a web page?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-applications

I'm developing a web site as well as windows application and i'm going to use same web page for windows form application as well as for web site.

so i want to call the windows form control after clicking on the link which is placed on the web page. And i want to show the windows form control as a pop up form.

How to do this? Or provide some document related to this issue.

Comment: Take a look at these articles: 1. [Hosting a Windows Control in a Web Form](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx)
2. [Hosting .NET Windows Forms Controls in IE](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c19639)

Comment: for all the above solution i have to change my windows form as user control. But i don't want to do this. Because that forms already i'm using in my windows form application. IS there any other solution?

Comment: You may write WPF browser app and host the winform app - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that within your WinForms application you're hosting an instance of the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class, you can provide an object to its [`ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) property. that provides a method to call to trigger your WinForms code. For example:

```
public partial class MyWindowsFormsForm()
{
    public MyWindowsFormsForm()
    {
        this.WebBrowserControl.ObjectForScripting = this;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MyOtherForm f = new MyOtherForm();
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Then, in your page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function loadOtherForm()
{
    if (RunningInWinFormsApplication())
    {
        window.external.DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        // Code to do something when NOT running inside the WinForms app could go here
    }
}

function RunningInWinFormsApplication()
{
   return (window.external.DoSomething != undefined);
}
</script>

<button onclick="loadOtherForm();">Call into WinForms app</button>
```

There's the obvious caveat that you'll need to have code in your web page that checks to ensure that `window.external.DoSomething` is actually there, so likely your `onclick` (in this example) would call a helper method that either calls into WinForms, or does whatever needs doing in the event that the page isn't being hosted inside your application.

Comment: can u provide some more info on what u r saying ?

Comment: @Priyanka - I've provided sample code and links to the documentation on MSDN that itself contains a further example. What part is it you need more info on, assuming that the msdn documentation doesn't answer any further questions you have? =)

Comment: I worked on the method which u have said. I have web page which i designed for web application and i'm going to open the same web page in the web browser control which will be placed on the one of form of windows form application.

Comment: And if i open the form which is having my web site page and i clicked on the link from the web page then that time it should open the another form from the windows application. In above example provided by msdn, i have to write the html code of web page it self on the form containing web browser control. But i don't want to change my form code. Opening of form or web site page decision should be taken on the web page itself not on the windows form application.

Comment: @Priyanka, that's because the msdn one is an example - it writes out the HTML to keep the sample code simple and self-contained, the HTML can just as easily be in a separate file that you cause the `WebBrowser` control to nagivate to. What happens in the `DoSomething()` method in the form is entirely up to you =)

Comment: but i don't want to write DoSomething() method on my form. It should be within the web page itself

Comment: @Priyanka, all the `DoSomething` method is is the bit of code that lets you do ".net stuff". You *have* to put the code that opens the new WinForms window in there. I've updated my answer to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your getting confused - or we are.

> "I have web page which i designed for web application and i'm going to
>   open the same web page in the web browser control which will be placed
>   on the one of form of windows form application. And if i open the form
>   which is having my web site page and i clicked on the link from the
>   web page then that time it should open the another form from the
>   windows application"

So you know the link that will be clicked? Then in the [WebBrowser Navigating Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx)
check if its the link you were expecting and open the WinForm, eg:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Url.Tostring() == "http://localhost/LinkThatOpensFormTwo.htm")
{
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can display Windows Form in Web Browser (Internet Explorer Preferred) by using WPF Browser Application** which have a facility to embed Windows Forms (or similar like .NET Components).

This is a valid Question because **there are lots of Legacy .NET Applications which company don't have resources to be developed for Web HTML 5 format** (using AJAX etc). Such legacy applications can be easily displayed in a web browser with a minor initial setup required.

1. Open your Windows Form Application in your existing Visual Studio IDE
2. Go to Project Properties and in Application Settings Set output Type to 'Class Library' [image]
3. Add a new project of Type 'WPF Browser Application' as shown below [image]
4. Reference your Windows Form (Now as DLL) along with two important assemblies of **WindowsFormIntegration** and **System.Windows.Forms**
5. Write the code to call Windows Form in XAML and XAML.CS page as shown [in this tutorial link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne).
6. Rebuild the Solution and Click on Publish and Save select File System as shown below. [image]
7. Go to Publish Folder and double click file with extension '.xbap. It should get automatically opened in Internet Explorer with permissions asking for the first time.
8. You should be able to display the output in Web Browser. [image]

Let me know **if you want me to create a video tutorial** to achieve the same.