# I Need help turning an idea in pseudocode into vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, pseudocode, vb.net-2010

I am trying to user a webbrowser control to interact with a webpage, there is a specific element that I need to interact with, but for the life of me I cant, tried invoking by id, href, src, element image, movie, and hell even bgcolor but to no avail. So then I came upon this idea and I structured it into sort of pseudocode and now need help realising it in code.

- create variable type point.
- set point to where I click in the browser (kind of like getelementfrompoint, but I couldnt get it to work)
- msgbox = point to string
- set html element to point
- invoke html element("click")`

Can anybody help me with this?
EDIT:
Thanks for the answer, however as stated ive tried invoking by element id, however there are several id tags, i cant tell which one is the correct one(my knowledge of HTML is limited) however i tried all the ones that i could find that purtained to the object in question, but none worked, here is the HTML purtaining to the object

```
 <div id="button">
            <script type="text/javascript">                                         function disableButton() {                          btn = document.getElementById('sbutton');                           btn.style.display = 'none';                         btn_clicked = document.getElementById('sbutton_clicked');                           btn.style.display = 'block';                        }                                       </script>
                <div id="sbutton" style="z-index:1">                        
                <script language="javascript">
                        AC_FL_RunContent(
                            'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
                            'width', '373',
                            'height', '373',
                            'src', '/images/buttons/',
                            'quality', 'high',
                            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                            'align', 'middle',
                            'play', 'false',
                            'loop', 'true',
                            'scale', 'showall',
                            'wmode', 'transparent',
                            'devicefont', 'false',
                            'id', '',
                            'bgcolor', '#ddeef6',
                            'name', '',
                            'menu', 'true',
                            'allowFullScreen', 'false',
                            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                            'movie', '/images/buttons/button_2',
                            'salign', ''
); //end AC code
                    </script><embed style="z-index:1;position:relative" width="373" height="373" src="/images/buttons/button_2.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" align="middle" play="false" loop="true" scale="showall" wmode="transparent" devicefont="false" bgcolor="#ddeef6" name="" menu="true" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" salign="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                    <noscript>
                        &lt;object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="373" height="373" id="" align="middle" style="z-index:1"&gt;
                            &lt;param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /&gt;
                            &lt;param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /&gt;
                            &lt;param name="movie" value="/images/buttons/button_2.swf" /&gt;&lt;param name="quality" value="high"    /&gt;&lt;param name="bgcolor" value="#ddeef6" /&gt;   &lt;embed src="/images/buttons/.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ddeef6" width="373" height="373" name="" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /&gt;
&lt;!-- no_flash content --&gt;
                            &lt;a href="/button/push_the_button" data-method="post" onmousedown="disableButton();return false;" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img alt="sbutton" src="/images/sb/sbutton.jpg?1331667296" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                            &lt;!-- end no_flash content --&gt;
                        &lt;/object&gt;
                    </noscript>
                </div>
                <div id="sbutton_clicked" style="display:none">
                    <img alt="sbutton" src="/images/sb/sbutton.jpg?1331667296">
                </div>
        </div>
```

i have tried button sbutton invoking the .swf (I did play, however I don't think I did click so ill go and try that now) also tried sbutton_clicked etc couldnt find a single one that would activate it. am now lost completely and just spitballing.
any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. *Please note this question is overly-broad. Please read the http://https://stackoverflow.com/FAQ,   http://whathaveyoutried.com and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not before you post your next question, thanks.*

1,2 & 3)

http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/jss3p2.html

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>XY Coordinates</TITLE>

<SCRIPT Language = javascript>

function XYpos() {
xPos = event.screenX
yPos = event.screenY
alert(xPos + " left " + yPos + " down")
}

</Script>

</HEAD>

<BODY onMouseDown = XYpos()>
```

Or try this example: http://www.brenz.net/snippets/xy.asp

4) https://www.google.com.au/search?q=set+html+element+to+point

5) You could invoke the click via Javascript or VB.Net:

```
Private Function ClickSubmitButton()
    Dim theButton As HtmlElement

    Try

        ' Link the ID from the web form to the Button var
        theButton = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("htmlElementId")

        ' Now do the actual click.
        theButton.InvokeMember("click")
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

If you want to control this more in VB.Net code rather than javascript (as shown for point 5) you could try techniques like this: [how to open windows form control in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157352/how-to-open-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page/9170914#9170914)